# Change the queryset in a empty_form

Tags: django, django-forms

i got som classes

```
class person
class organization
class relation
    person = ForeignKey(person)
    organization = ForeignKey(organization)
    what = ForeignKey(...)
```

i want to set some relations for one person with an formset:

```
InlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(person, relation, form=Form)
Formset = InlineFormset(initial=[...])
```

To add forms to the formset in the template I generate new ones with Formset.empty_form. The default queryset for Formset.forms[0].fields['organization'] is Organization.objects.all()

The person must not see all organizations so i want to change the queryset for the empty_form.

I can change this queryset easily for all forms made by initial=[...], but when I try to change Formset.empty_form.fields['organization'].queryset it wont work. Django discards all changes for the empty_form.

I have also tried to change the queryset in the form used by the formset but it wont help too.

How can i setup the queryset for empty_form? Thanks!

Comment: I know you did this years ago, but I am curious to know what solution you used for your case.  How did you manipulate the empty form?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584675/limiting-queryset-for-foreign-key-for-inline-formset-in-django